# not familiar with c++ pointer, need help

Tags: c++, pointers

on the line `*binSon[0].add(x);`, it give me an error, an expression must have a class type, what do i do?

```
struct Rectangle
{
    tName Name; //name of the rectangle
    struct Rectangle *binSon[NDIR_1D]; //left and right son
    int Center[NDIR_1D];
    int Length[NDIR_1D];

    void add(Rectangle x){
        if(strcmp(x.Name,Name)<0)
        {
            if(binSon[0]==NULL)
                binSon[0]=&x;
            else
                *binSon[0].add(x);

        }else{
            if(binSon[1]==NULL)
                binSon[1]=&x;
            else
                *binSon[1].add(x);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the past response, i forgot about ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here really isn't quite what you think, although it can be solved as is.

The *correct* syntax is:

```
binSon[0]->add(x);
```

The `->` operator is member-of-pointer, which handles everything for you. Typically, `->` should be used with pointers and `.` with references or the object itself (the exceptions are in interesting spots).

To do it how you want (which you really shouldn't), `(*binSon[0]).add(x)` should work. The precedence of the operator is likely your issue at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You have a small precedence issue. Either of the following should fix the problem:

```
(*binSon[0]).add(x);
```

or

```
binSon[0]->add(x);
```

Same applies to the other line.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want `(*binSon[0]).add` or better yet `binSon[0]->add`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `.` has higher precedence than `*`, so when you write `*binSon[1].add(x)`, it means `*(binSon[1].add(x))`, which isn't what you want. You can write `(*binSon[1]).add(x)`, or better, `binSon[1]->add(x)`, which is syntactic sugar for it.